# How to input ordinal data into daisy function

Tags: r, r-daisy

I have a data set with 12 variables each taking values 1 to 4 and are to be treated as ordinal. If I don't specify their type, they are being treated as interval type

```
> attributes(gower_dist)
$class
[1] "dissimilarity" "dist"         

$Size
[1] 5845

$Metric
[1] "mixed"

$Types
 [1] "I" "I" "I" "I" "I" "I" "I" "I" "I" "I" "I" "I"
```

but if I add 'type=list(ordratio=1:12)', the type becomes 'T' and I'm sure what that stands for. If it doesnt stand for ordinal, then how do I tell daisy that I am inputting ordinal data?

```
> attributes(gower_dist)
$class
[1] "dissimilarity" "dist"         

$Size
[1] 5845

$Metric
[1] "mixed"

$Types
 [1] "T" "T" "T" "T" "T" "T" "T" "T" "T" "T" "T" "T"
```

Comment: Care to share a proper reproducible example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**:

If you specified ordinal ratios & observe the resulting type to be "T", that's the expected behaviour.

**Long answer**:

I took a look inside the `daisy` function. There are 6 possible values for the `Types` attribute:

```
typeCodes <- c("A", "S", "N", "O", "I", "T")
```

I cycled through the function in debug mode a couple of times with different parameters. The mapping appears to be as follows for this attribute:

- If you specify `type = list(asymm=<whichever columns in the dataset>)`: "A"
- If you specify `type = list(symm=<whichever columns in the dataset>)`: "S"
- If you specify `type = list(ordratio=<whichever columns in the dataset>)`: "T"

If you *don't* specify type, or you specify `type=list(logratio=<whichever columns in the dataset>)`, & your dataset's columns are:

- factors: "N"
- ordered: "O"
- numeric / integers: "I"

(Not sure why logratio doesn't get its own type, but that's probably going off topic here...)